# Where are the admin panel pages in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

When you go to **Catalog->Manage Products** you can search a product by its SKU. I need to make a change in the page so I can put some restrictions in this search. How can I find which page is fired when you search by SKU ?

Answer (score 0):

you should override magento base module for make any kind of default changes of magento.